# Creating an interactive lab environment with a server

Tags: server, lan, ubuntu-server

I want to install an interactive lab environment in which students can code within that environment. I want to use codeboard.io for the IDE part. But, I don't want students to access the Internet apart from codeboard.io. So, how can disable the Internet access except codeboard.io?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different tools which help you lock down a system and limit what students can do in the browser. One software I remember and which was used at my university is [Safe Exam Browser](https://www.safeexambrowser.org).

As far as I can tell it's free and open source.